# Why are the answerer's and editor's names swapped on the mobile app?

Tags: bug, design, android-app, mobile-web

I noticed this morning reading my news letter in bed that on the Android mobile app, the answerers name is displayed on the left, and the editor on the right. On the web though, it is the other way round like I'm used to. Is this intended?

[image: screenshot of mobile app]

[image: screenshot of desktop view]

Comment: probably because you read it from bed.

Comment: It is kind of weird to see yourself in a screenshot.

Comment: Probably to ensure that full card of the answerer is visible, while some portion of the editor's card might be cropped due to width limitation.

Comment: I think it's by design - just sides swapped.

Comment: [MSE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287953/attribution-alignment-and-order-should-be-consistent-with-the-website), for the iOS app at least.

Comment: Left to right chronology makes more sense to me anyway. Change the site to match the app!

Comment: @canon, I disagree. It's better to maintain the current desktop usage with the author on the right, primarily to maintain the UI which everyone is used to. While I don't know the actual source for the original choice for this placement, I presume it continues the customary placement from written works, where a signature is often placed on the right of the page with notes about modifications in the center or on the left. In addition, the author *always* exists. Having their information in a static place (on right) is better than moving them over to the center when someone has edited the post.

Comment: The left side could easily be the new static place.

Answer (score -9):

I support Canon's suggestion

> Left to right chronology makes more sense to me anyway. Change the site to match the app!

Comment: I'm left-handed.

Comment: @SteveFest what on Earth does your handedness have to do with chronological representation? Do timelines start at the end for left-handed people? I'm missing out...

Comment: @canon So you don't care about left-handed people?

Comment: @SteveFest I reiterate, _"what on Earth does your handedness have to do with chronological representation?"_

Comment: @canon The current "LTR" chronology is designed for **ease of usage** for right handed. While "RTL" is designed for **ease of usage** for left handed person. *Note I said "designed for ease of usage", not "designed specifically"*.